# Create AEM packages via code

Tags: java, package, aem

Is there a way to create an AEM package via a java code ?
We need to package some content every night via a service run by a cron job.

I checked online and it seems to be possible using a curl command. But either way, I'd need this done via a daily service running a java code.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to some of the links given below :
1)https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/dynamic_aem_packages.html

2)http://cq5experiences.blogspot.in/2014/01/creating-packages-using-java-code-in-cq5.html

The main code goes something like this  :

```
        final JcrPackage jcrPackage = getPackageHelper().createPackageFromPathFilterSets(packageResources,
                request.getResourceResolver().adaptTo(Session.class),
                properties.get(PACKAGE_GROUP_NAME, getDefaultPackageGroupName()),
                properties.get(PACKAGE_NAME, getDefaultPackageName()),
                properties.get(PACKAGE_VERSION, DEFAULT_PACKAGE_VERSION),
                PackageHelper.ConflictResolution.valueOf(properties.get(CONFLICT_RESOLUTION,
                        PackageHelper.ConflictResolution.IncrementVersion.toString())),
                packageDefinitionProperties
        );
```

So first of all you can create a scheduler and in the scheduler's run method you can write the logic to package the required filter paths .

Hoping this is helpful for you.

Comment: Is it possible to translate the path when we create package like /content/dam/abc to /content/dam/bcd ?